# Have great difficulty with SSH ... following steps and gets messier each step

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have just spent 4 hours trying to get this working... including 3 with a mid level tech. Seems so very hard to do basic things to connect to a compute engine?

Here's some of the errors:

1. I've got connect to 1 instance/project under 1 email account and it works using this style of connection:
   ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no cam@
2. I have create a new account of google cloud (different email). Created a new ssh key on my mac computer. and tried to load that key to the new server via the google ssh console. Then try to do the same thing changing the username and the ip and I keep getting this error below from my terminal on my mac:
   Camerons-MacBook-Pro:~ cam$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o CheckHostIP=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no @
   Warning: Permanently added '' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
   **Permission denied (publickey).**

Any ideas?

Comment: I have had these problems before. If you have a few host keys on your computer now make sure you are using the correct one. You can find the host keys here, ~/.ssh go there terminal cd ~/.ssh and make sure you are trying to connect with the right one.

Comment: sounds reasonable... though how do i now what the right one is? : )

Comment: This is what is on my mac:                                     google_compute_engine  id_rsa
google_compute_engine.pub id_rsa.pub
id_dsa    known_hosts
id_dsa.pub

Comment: I guarantee you this is the solution considering you just asked me that question haha I duno bro. I use AWS in the same way. So If I got confused I could login and download a new key and name it. Are you possible using the name of your first key with your second install?  If so you can login and turn off that kind of authentication.. allowing you to just login with a password. I hate the whole using annoying key thing that makes you search to figure out which key goes with what. especially on osx cause it saves them to some  hidden file that you didn't even know about.

Comment: yes it looks like you have two. try both of them

Comment: ok. I'll do my best now the tech get has gone... :) much apprecaited

Comment: No problem. if I answered your question please accept my answer. Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you are using the correct key to login. If you have made more than one instance of a google serve chances are you have downloaded two keys and didn't notice. Each keys should be used with the respective server.

I have had these problems before. If you have a few host keys on your computer now make sure you are using the correct one. You can find the host keys here, `~/.ssh` go there terminal `cd ~/.ssh` and make sure you are trying to connect with the right one

Once you are logged in you can set a linux install up to allow you to use only a password to login without the key.

Check  these file paths and make sure to set this setting.

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config and /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

PasswordAuthentication yes
```

[from the google site](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys)

```
username:ssh-rsa PUBLIC_KEY username[@host]
```

Make sure to declare the correct key when you type in the command in the terminal.

Comment: ok so to set it do i take away the '#' inline? sorry to be such a newby :(

Comment: no problem bro, Please explain better I don't know what you mean, take away the #

Comment: Oh ya in the file you are in you mean. Yes # means that the row is commented out. I am sorry man I didn't know what you were talking about.. I was just playing a video game and it dawned on me hahaha. By the way I upvoted you question so you didnt start in the negative. People can be pretty mean around here. Make sure when you ask questions you state the question clearly and add examples of your problem as well as code you have tried. Then tell us what happens with the code you tried. any errors etc. Remember huge walls of code are usually not necessary but you will get a lot better feedback